# Expected Sum of 30 sided die rolls

Tags: probability

Roll a 30-sided die. Add up each consecutive outcome. Stop rolling when the sum >= 300. What's the most likely result of the sum?

Comment: are the values of the dice's sides $1\ldots 30$?

Comment: This seems related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/380004).

Comment: The expected sum and the most likely result are completely different things. Expected sum, at least for me, seems that should be interpreted as [expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) while most likely is the value which maximizes the probability.

Answer (score 21):

Clearly $300$.  You have $30$ chances for what the sum was before, while for $329$ you only have one.   If the target is above the maximum value on the die, the most likely stopping place is the target. Let $P(n)$ be the chance that $n$ is the last total before you hit or pass $300$.  It may depend on $n$, but is greater than zero for all $270 \le n \le 299$.  The chance you hit $300$ is $\sum_{i=270}^{299}P(i)\frac 1{i-269}.$  The $\frac 1{i-269}$ term comes because we know we must roll a large enough number to hit or exceed $300$, but the acceptable numbers are equally distributed.  The chance you hit  $301$ is $\sum_{i=271}^{299}P(i)\frac 1{i-269}.$  The chance you hit  $302$ is $\sum_{i=272}^{299}P(i)\frac 1{i-269}.$ and so on until the chance you hit  $329$ is $\sum_{i=299}^{299}P(i)\frac 1{i-269}.$  Each successive sum has one less positive term, so the sums are strictly decreasing.

Comment: Funny: I understand neither the argument in the post nor the objection to it in the comment. @Ross 300 and 329 are not the only possible sums.

Comment: Roll a 6-sided die. Stop rolling when the sum >= 2. What's the most likely result of the sum? It's not 2.

Comment: I just tried this experiment. 64 trials, only one of which resulted in 300. I know the number of trials is small, but the average was 309.75.

Comment: @Landscape: I'm not trying to say that Ross is incorrect, merely that he ought to elaborate, because his reasoning isn't convincing.

Comment: @Did:  Yes, I know the in between results are possible.  But these are the end cases.

Comment: @EricTressler:  As Landscape says, if the target is above the maximum value on the die, the most likely stopping place is the target.  In this case the chance you hit $300$ is $\frac 1{30}$ times the sum of the chances you hit $270,271,272,\dots,299$.  The chance you hit $329$ is $\frac 1{30}$ times the chance you hit $299$.  Intermediate values are in between.  There is clear domination between them as each lower value has all the chances for a higher value, plus some.

Comment: @Phil:  The question was for the most likely, not the average.  I think your average is very close.

Comment: Alright, it looks like I was wrong and Ross' answer is correct. @RossMillikan I still think your answer would benefit from a little elaboration. It's not "clearly" to me, or, I assume, some other people.

Comment: Ross, my only objection is your use of the word "chance" in the post (especially since you use it in a different, and more conventional, way in the comments).

Comment: Dear Ross Millikan and @EricTressler: Sorry for my stupid mistake and bothering.

Comment: Ross, if you roll 2d6, the most likely result is 7, because 7 has the greatest number of combinations between 1-6 and 1-6 to be reached.  Is the same not true for 270-300 (the window to reach the target range)?  Surely some of those values are more likely to come up.

Comment: @acolyte:  This is a different question.  The number of dice being rolled is not given.  You keep rolling until the total exceeds $300.$  That can only happen when the existing total is $270-299$.  The argument above shows why it is more likely to hit $300$ than any higher number.

Comment: @RossMillikan does that completely negate the increased chances of reaching any given "landing number"?

Comment: No, it doesn't negate them, but they don't matter to this question.  As long as the target is higher than the maximum number on the die, you will be more likely to reach the target than any higher number.  This is because you have more places to start to reach the target than any other number.

Comment: This assumes crucially that the die is fair (one cannot help to wonder how many upvoters realized this).

Comment: @Did:  That is correct.  I think when one talks of rolling a die one assumes it is fair unless specified otherwise.

Comment: No doubt the die is assumed to be fair. But the steps in your solution where this assumption is used could be made more apparent.

Comment: It is intuitively clear why this is the right answer, but I am having trouble proving it.  The probability of reaching any of 270,...,299 is not equal.

Comment: @user1354557:  True, but doesn't matter.  In fact they are quite close, but all that matters is they are all positive.  See my update.

Answer (score 11):

Ross Millikan's answer is based on the mathematical analysis, but to understand his solution I wrote a program and tested it anyway. Here are my results.

### Matlab Code Used

```
trials = 1000000;
results = zeros(1,trials);
for n = 1:trials
   sum = 0;
   while sum < 300
       sum = sum + ceil(30*rand);
   end
   results(n) = sum;
end
hist(results,30);
```

### Results

[image]

As stated by Ross Millikan, it is easy to see that 300 is the most likely result.

Comment: Or http://ideone.com/IUdLhK

Comment: For those interested, the triangular shape is not an accident and corresponds to the limit of the distribution of the overshoot of $n$ when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: +1. The graph makes it clear that the *average* (aka arithmetic mean) is going to be higher than 300, but the *mode* is what the question was actually asking about. This is one of the sticking points in the comments on @RossMillikan answer.

Comment: Nice. Some tips: Use `randi(30)` to generate random integers drawn uniformly from [1 30]. Always set a seed. You can use the `rng` function for that is recent versions of Matlab.

Answer (score 7):

Let $p_n$ be the probability of attaining the total $n$. Then we can reach $300$ by getting to $299$ and rolling $1$, or getting to $298$ and rolling $2$, or ... so that $$p_{300}=\frac 1{30}(p_{299}+p_{298}+ \dots + p_{270})$$

Then we get to $301$ by throwing $2$ from $299$ etc $$p_{301}=\frac 1{30}(p_{299}+p_{298}+\dots+p_{271})$$

The pattern is now obvious, as is the fact that the probabilities diminish as the target number increases.

I didn't post this originally because Ross Millikan had posted the essential insight. The probabilities below $300$ need not all be identical, but they are positive, and are intuitively similar in magnitude. This explains the steplike structure of the graph in Phil's solution. But because we know they are positive, we don't need to know their exact values to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Count the number of roll sequences (of some fixed but arbitrary lengtzh $l$) that lead to an outcome $s\ge 300$. For each such sequence that ends in $s>300$, we obtain a sequnce that ends in exactly $300$ by replacing the last roll $x$ (which must be $>s-300$) with $x+300-s$. This shows that the end sum $300$ is *at least* as probably as the end sum $s$.
Now since $300>30$, there is at least one sequence that ends in a sum of $300$ with a last roll of $30$. This sequence is not obtained from a sequence leading to end sum $s>300$ in the ways described above. Therefore, the number of sequences (of at least one specific length) leading to $300$ is *strictly* larger thanthe number of sequences of the same length leading to end sum $s$ if $s>300$.
Consequently, $300$ is the most likely end sum.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this question on the Statistics Blog twitter feed and thought it would be fun to sim.  I see someone already did so in matlab.  Here is the code for an `R` simul (10 reps of 50,000 simulations) and ggplot2 output with 2sd errorbars.

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(1)

## PARAMETERS
reps   <- 10   # number of reps to conduct
simuls <- 5e4  # number of simulations per rep
Sides <- 30    # number of dungeons and dragon playing friends that I have
StopVal <- 300 # the min value to reach before stopping

## FUNCTIONS
rollDie <- function(StopVal=300) {
  total <- 0
  while (total < StopVal) {
    total <- total + sample(Sides, 1, TRUE)
  }
  return(c(total=total))
}

tally <- function(res, i) {
    ret <- rev(table(res))
    ret / sum(ret)
    data.frame(Roll=as.numeric(names(ret)), Prob=ret/sum(ret), Trial=i)
}

## SIMULATE
rolls   <- lapply(seq(reps), function(i) replicate(simuls, rollDie(StopVal)))
results <- lapply(seq(reps), function(i) tally(rolls[[i]], i))

## AGGREGATE
dat <- do.call(rbind, results)
dat <- data.table(dat, key="Roll")
dat[, c("MeanProb", "SDProb") := list(mean(Prob), sd(Prob)), by=Roll]


## PLOT
P <- ggplot(dat[Trial==1], aes(x=as.factor(Roll), y=MeanProb)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="lightblue") +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=MeanProb-(2*SDProb), ymax=MeanProb+(2*SDProb)), width=.3, color="red") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, size=rel(0.75))) + 
    labs(x="Roll Total", y="Prob") + 
    ggtitle(paste0("d", Sides, " rolling X, X ≥ ", StopVal))

ggsave("~/d30_exceed300.png", plot=P)

P
```

[image: ggplot2]

Comment: Interesting. The question asks for $\ge 300$, not $>300$, but I think the right answer is clear nonetheless.

Comment: @Potato, thanks for pointing that out.  Simple enough to change the  parameter and re run with the correct value. (answer has been edited to reflect correct value)

Answer (score 0):

I computed the exact probabilities for this problem.  They involve nearly 1000 digits.

The probability that the final number is $300$ is approximately $$\frac{30}{\sum_{i=1}^{30} i} = \frac{2}{31}$$ to about thirty parts in a trillion.  The analogous expression holds for the other numbers, namely that the probability for $300+i$ is proportional to $30-i$.

Interpreting the question as about the *expectation* instead of *most likely* sum (as in the current question title), the answer is approximately $309 + 2/3$, again with the same margin of error.